# Get binary data from PDF (using JS), save it in db and get it back in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I have an issue with my binary data to convert it to a pdf.

I am using readAsBinaryString() in JS to get the binary data of an pdf file. I am storing it in my db (colunm type blob). Then I try to recreate a pdf in php using :

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $_POST["fileName"]);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo html_entity_decode($_POST["fileData"]);
```

I am using entity decode because I use entitieshtml before (as the binary data containt ">" and it's break my html.

I am able to get a pdf file, but it's say that the file is corrupt.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks

**Edit, it's working !** : Before inserting my binary data in DB, i convert it to base 64 data. Then, before the "echo" in my php script, where the file is generated, I use base64_decode.

And it's work fine ! I think my binary data was corrupted, because I was stocking it in a hidden input, before sending it to my php script !

Comment: `$_POST["fileName"]` contain extension? (name. **pdf** )

Comment: Yes ! Like "test.pdf"

It detect that the output is a pdf but when I open it, it say corrupted

Comment: Are you sure binary data is correct so?

Comment: Yes, I think I found the solution. Before inserting the binary data in db, I convert it into B64 data. Then, before the "echo", I use b64_decode. It's seam to work great ! 

Hours lost, to find the solution my self 10 mins after asking for help :(

Thanks for you help anyway :)

Comment: No problem ;)...